# Will TrueCrypt work with a multiboot system

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a 4 multiboot system (Windows 7, 8, 10, and Ubuntu) all on their own  partitions, with 2 storage partitions. If I encrypt one of the storage partitions in Windows 7 with TrueCrypt, will I be able to read it with Windows 8 or 10 if I install TrueCrypt on them?

Comment: Will what what be able to read it exactly?

Comment: Will my other OS,s read the encrypted partition

Comment: If you install Truecrypt on those operating system, then yes, those operating systems will be able to mount those partitions.  Of course you do understand that Truecrypt will not be updated, has known weaknesses, and most people who have used it have migrated to one of its successors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

But Windows 10 version of NTFS has new log format, so if TrueCrypt storage partition was not unmounted in Windows 10 cleanly (e.g. due to loss of power), it will require running a full disk check when mounted in Windows 8 or earlier. Windows will prompt for this automatically. This applies to non-TrueCrypt partitions as well.